# How to use DataType.Custom in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, types

Can anyone tell me how to use DataType.Custom in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `DataType.Custom`.

Instead use `[DataType("YourCustomDataTypeHere")]` with an editor/display template named `YourCustomDataTypeHere`.

Comment: To expand a little on MushinNoShin's answer, create a new file here: Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\YourCustomDataTypeHere.cshtml

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it personally, but looking at the MSDN it seems to just be a matter of setting `DataType = DataType.Custom` and `CustomDataType = "String"`. Then when you process your model you would check for DataType.Custom and if found perform different operations based on the value in CustomDataType.

Here's the sample they give on the [MSDN - How to: Customize Data Field Appearance and Behavior For Non-Intrinsic Data Types in the Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668199.aspx):

```cs
public partial class TextField : System.Web.DynamicData.FieldTemplateUserControl {

    string getNavUrl() {

        var metadata = MetadataAttributes.OfType<DataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (metadata == null)
            return FieldValueString; 

        switch (metadata.DataType) {

            case DataType.Url:
                string url = FieldValueString;
                if (url.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    url.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return url;

                return "http://" + FieldValueString;


            case DataType.EmailAddress:
                return "mailto:" + FieldValueString;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown DataType");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnDataBinding(e);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FieldValueString))
            return;

        var metadata = MetadataAttributes.OfType<DataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (metadata == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(FieldValueString)) {
            Literal literal = new Literal();
            literal.Text = FieldValueString;
            Controls.Add(literal);
            return;
        }

        if (metadata.DataType == DataType.Url ||
            metadata.DataType == DataType.EmailAddress) {

            HyperLink hyperlink = new HyperLink();
            hyperlink.Text = FieldValueString;
            hyperlink.NavigateUrl = getNavUrl();
            hyperlink.Target = "_blank";
            Controls.Add(hyperlink);
            return;
        }

        if (metadata.DataType == DataType.Custom &&
           string.Compare(metadata.CustomDataType, "BoldRed", true) == 0) {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = FieldValueString;
            lbl.Font.Bold = true;
            lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Controls.Add(lbl);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd read over Brad Wilson's ASP.NET MVC 2 Template series on his blog [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).  It explains what you're asking better than I could.

Hope that helps.